# How to drill down or slice and dice word cloud

Tags: python, nlp, powerbi, data-visualization, word-cloud

Say I have two columns in my data set, **State** and **Comments**. This is basically the comments given by people from different state. I want to analyse the comments column, say I want to see the most used word by a particular state. For eg Comments of people belonging to Texas. I want to create a bar chart or a word cloud for these data and I want it to change correspondingly when i click or choose a particular state.
For eg. Say there is a word cloud showing responses of the entire data set. Now if i click on Texas, my word cloud should change correspondingly showing responses from Texas alone

So what is the best of doing it? can it be done in Power Bi or python? If so, kindly tell me how to go about it.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first.... You should provide a sample of your dataset so that we are able to reproduce it.... Also ideally you should try it first and give some code ( even if it has errors.... ) Because it's also good to practice yourself.... But definitely you can use Python, the idea for example would be to create a list per state with all the comments, and you just return the word that appears more often. That is very doable. But please provide some sample of the data

Comment: i did not post a sample because i just wanted to get an idea on how to approach such a problem. Appreciate your response though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Word Cloud](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380752) custom visual for that. You need to install it first, before you can use it in your report. Just click `GET IT NOW` button and follow the instructions.

Following your question, lets say you have table like this:

[image]

Then place a slicer visual and add `State` field to it. It should look like this:

[image]

Then place Word Cloud visual in your report and add `Comment` field as Word Cloud's category, like this:

[image]

Now when there is nothing selected in the slicer, you will see the data from all states. If you want to see data for particular state, select it in the slicer. To see data from more than one state, hold Ctrl key to select more than one item in the slicer.

UPDATE: In case you need to simply count word occurrences, then you can split comments by space (use `Split column -> By delimeter` command from the ribbon for example). If you split `Comment` column by space, unpivot all resulting `Comment.x` columns to get a table with columns for state and word, for simplicity add a custom int column `Word count` with constant value of 1, you can analyze word counts in tables and charts (and add a slicer for the state to filter the data):

[image]

But there will be many "noise words", which you will want to take care of. You may also want to take a look at [Azure Cognitive Services Text Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/).

Comment: I’m glad I could help! Accepting my answer and upvoting it will be appreciated too :)

Comment: Sorry, upvoted now :) and is there a way to get the word and the frequency of that word so that i can see the trend in it . Word cloud looks great but I still couldn't figure out the important or maximum occurring words. So thought something like a bar chart with the word and it's frequency would be great to better visualize.
I can do this using python but want to know if its possible in power BI

Comment: I don't see any upvotes, but anyway, I updated my answer to show you how you can count words and visualize this in tables and charts :)

Comment: thanks a lot.  And just so you know when i upvoted your comment it said "people with less than 15 reputations are recorded but not publicly shown". I just created my stack overflow profile. So my account is pretty new and hence you cant see it